# Using cat to combine files with numerical names that must be kept in order

Tags: bash

I have a number of files (these are randomly generated each time) that have a number in the name – within the file, the number is repeated.  Example:

```
file1_85.txt
file1_242.txt
file1_9.txt
```

I want to cat the contents of these files into one larger file, `file_all.txt`.

The code that I tried using is this:

```
for f in file1_*.txt; do (cat "${f}"; echo " ") >> file_all.txt; done
```

However, the contents of `file_all.txt` look like this:

```
file1_242.txt
file1_85.txt
file1_9.txt
```

When I really want it to look like this:

```
file1_9.txt
file1_85.txt
file1_242.txt
```

Which would happen if bash cat the files in numerical order.

I have tried this:

```
for f in file1_{1..99999}.txt; do (cat "${f}"; echo " ") >> file_all.txt; done
```

Which worked, however I got error messages "No such file or directory" when it passed through a number that did not have a matching file.  Also, this is very time consuming.  Is there a better way to carry out this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the files don't have any newlines in their names, and you have the GNU version of `sort`, this will work:

```
while read file; do 
   cat "$file"
   echo 
done < <(ls -1 file_*.txt | sort -V) > file_all.txt
```

If your `sort` doesn't support `-V` (as on e.g. OS X), you can take advantage of the filename consistency to do a straight numeric sort instead:

```
while read file; do 
   cat "$file"
   echo 
done < <(ls -1 file_*.txt | sort -t_ -n -k2,2) > file_all.txt
```

Finally, if your files contain newlines, you can still use `sort`, but you need to use the `-z` option in conjunction with other tools that terminate elements of a  list with NUL bytes instead of newlines:

```
find . -depth 1 -name 'file_*' -print0 | sort -zV | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'cat {}; echo'
```

Replace the `sort -zV` with `sort -z -t_ -n -k2,2` for an older version of GNU sort that lacks the `-V` option; a totally non-GNU sort probably won't have `-z` either, though.

Comment: Oops, I wrote that answer after seeing the comment, then the comment was removed again... makes for a bit of redundancy now.

Comment: Sorry.  Rethought. Noticed your answer was missing the `.` on the find and `-z` on the sort and figured I'd just add to my answer rather than have a back-and-forth about yours - and then you edited your comment.  A pox on comment editing! :)

Answer (score 4):

For filenames potentially containing newlines:

```
$ find -name 'file1*' -print0 | sort -zV | xargs -0 cat
file1_9
file1_85
file1_242
```

or, if the `-V` option is not available,

```
$ find -name 'file1*' -print0 | sort -z -n -t '_' -k 2 | xargs -0 cat
file1_9
file1_85
file1_242
```

This uses null separated filenames; the `-z` option tells `sort` to expect (and produce) null separated filenames, and `xargs -0` is for null separated input as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your "brute force" approach would work if:

```
$ for f in file1_{1..99999}.txt; do [ -f "${f}" ] && cat "${f}" >> file_all.txt; done
```

The comparison: `[ -f "${f}" ]` check if the file exists before `cat`, avoiding the error message.

Comment: The error is also harmless beyond the appearance of the message, which is sent to stderr and therefore won't appear in the concatenated file regardless. Could just ignore it or put `2>/dev/null` on the end and be done.